# How can I use two fragment shaders on one texture in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am trying to do a blur effect with a shader in cocos2d 2.0. I have two fragement shaders, one for the horizontal direction and one for the vertical. They both work, but I need to be able to use both of them to get a blur in both directions. And I can't figure how how to use two fragment shaders on the same sprite, since you can only attach one shader program to a sprite. Is there any special way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about in Cocos2d, but in OpenGL (which I assume Cocos2d relies on), you need to create a frame buffer object (FBO), that is backed by a texture. You do the first pass into the FBO, then use the texture you just wrote to as the input to the next pass.

Comment: I don't think you can assign two fragment shaders to the same texture. Instead merge your shader's code into one.

Comment: I read that for blur effect you want to do it in two passes or the performance is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a 'solution'.

You can use CCRenderTexture, and draw the sprite with the first Shader on to it, and then use the result of that to run a second Shader on top of that.

Its not ideal but it works.